# Illustrator "Save for Web & Devices" returning crappy, pixelated images

Tags: graphics, adobe-illustrator

I'm trying to create a nice title for my webpage... a big white title to sit on a black background. I'm using Illustrator to do so. When I create it, it looks nice, but when I hit "save for web & devices", it comes out looking like a pixelated piece of crap on the site. Is there some setting I need to change to make Illustrator save a higher resolution image? Thanks

**EDIT** I understand, from looking at some other posts, that this may be a result of "posterization" or "dither", but this is only a plain white image so I don't how this results in a colors problem. (I could be completely misinterpreting these terms)

**EDIT** Figured version might be important... I'm using CS5.1

Answer (score 2):

Below the preset area, on the save for web dialog, there should be a small tab that says "Image Size" and in there, a small panel says New Size and percent, try 200 percent or higher. don't forget to hit the apply button.

You may also try the 2 up on the upper left corner so you can compare them side by side.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a higher resolution; change your document units to pixels and turn the rulers on (Ctrl+R). Zoom to 100% (Ctrl+0), make the graphic exactly the size you want, and export it at screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

When you 'Save for Web', under 'Image Size' ensure the "Art Optimised" is selected. Mine was on 'none' and produced crappy pixelated results.